# spring maven web application giving error 500

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, model-view-controller

The web application was working fine earlier but when i ran it after fortnight its giving me an error . I am not using the servlet its built using Hibernet spring mvc with maven

Below is the error :-

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - javax.el.ELException: JBWEB006003: Cannot convert **Nov** of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report

JBWEB000068: message javax.el.ELException: JBWEB006003: Cannot convert Nov of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: JBWEB006003: Cannot convert Nov of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:409)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
JBWEB000071: root cause

javax.el.ELException: JBWEB006003: Cannot convert Nov of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long
    org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:298)
    org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:278)
    org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.equals(ELSupport.java:143)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:40)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstChoice.getValue(AstChoice.java:45)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:898)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspx_meth_jstl_005fforEach_005f0(welcome_jsp.java:259)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspx_meth_jstl_005fif_005f0(welcome_jsp.java:199)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fform_005f0(welcome_jsp.java:138)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java:79)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
JBWEB000072: note JBWEB000073: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1 logs.

JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1
```

it seems that nov in the first line is picked from data base

Comment: Can you provide JSP file that causes this problem?

Comment: @PiotrPodraza not sure which jsp has code as this was developed by some one else

Comment: In the code itselt is clearly displaying error right
   --- JBWEB006003: Cannot convert Nov of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long---Please check from where this error is coming or from where this value is passed.

Comment: @PrasadReddy the code is working fine with old version of java and jBoss. But when I am updating the code to java 7 and jboss 6.x its giving me this error